# No such column 'PersonOtherStreet' on entity 'Account'

Tags: soql, api

I am trying to execute a query where i am fetching `PersonOtherStreet` field from Account. But its showing this error

> No such column 'PersonOtherStreet' on entity 'Account'

If it is ApI version related issue than how could i know that this field is related to which API version.

Comment: Is this a custom field?

Comment: Let me ask a better question: do you have person accounts enabled on your organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'**PersonOtherStreet**' field is available only for Person Accounts. If your organization if not enabled with Person Accounts, you won't be able to access this field.

[Account Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_fields.htm) for your Reference

[What is Person Account](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDochttps://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_person.htm&language=en_US) for your reference.

Comment: If the comment answered or clarified your Question, please mark it as Accepted.